# All headers enabled in Cors, no conflicts between WebConfig and WebApiConfig, why is my WebApi returning a 405 error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, cors

I tried the top answers in other posts with no success, it seems only GET and POST  are allowed despite my best efforts. The only thing I can think of is an IIS issue? As you can likely tell I am new to this.

```
**Response Header**
```

Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* 
Allow:GET,POST
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:82
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 09 Mar 2016 13:49:26 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8BQzpcVXNlcnNcTWVcRGVza3RvcFxDb2RlXERldlxwbTJcUHJvcGVydHlNYW5hZ2VyMlxhcGlcdGVuYW50cw==?=

```
**Request Header**
```

Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Content-Length:105
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Host:localhost:62118
Origin:http://localhost:54633
Proxy-Connection:keep-alive
Referer:http://localhost:54633/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.75 Safari/537.36

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(
              origins: "*",
              headers: "*",
              methods: "*"
          );

        config.EnableCors(cors);

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        SetupAutomapper();

        var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
        json.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    }


    private static void SetupAutomapper()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Property, PropertyModel>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<Tenant, TenantModel>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<Lease, LeaseModel>();
    }
}
```

And my Controller

```
// PUT: api/Tenants/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public IHttpActionResult PutTenant(int id, TenantModel tenant)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != tenant.TenantId)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        var dbTenant= db.Tenants.Find(id);

        dbTenant.Update(tenant);

        db.Entry(dbTenant).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!TenantExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
```

Lastly, web.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301879
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings></appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Do you have installed WebDAV?

Comment: I couldn't find WebDav anywhere in my solution, no.

Comment: The WebDav is a program that can be installed on your computer. Please check and uninstall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your config of IIS.

- Open applicationHost.config in the `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\IISExpress\config` folder.
- Find `ExtensionlessUrl` in `handlers` section
- Add `PUT` to the verb attribute

Result should be like:

```
<add name="ExtensionlessUrl-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT"....
```

and

```
<add name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT" ...
```

Comment: No luck, should those be the only two lines I'm editing? I see a lot with verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG"

Comment: @TJTJ Yes, only 2 lines and try to restart your IIS